# Were the 1934 St Louis Cardinals Team the Inspiration for Daffy Duck?

Tags: origin, looney-tunes

The following [commentator](http://fivethirtyeight.com/contributors/nate-silver/) [writes](https://twitter.com/NateSilver538/status/725367286429798400):

> Historical baseball discoveries:
>
> - Dazzy Vance was amazing.
> - The '34 Cardinals had Dizzy Dean, **Daffy** Dean, Dazzy Vance and **Ducky** Medwick.

Now we know that this relates to the [1934 World Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1934_World_Series). The [St. Louis Cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Louis_Cardinals) had two players, Dizzy and [Daffy Dean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Dean_(baseball)). They also had a team member [Ducky Medwick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Medwick).

My question is: **Were the 1934 St Louis Cardinals Team the Inspiration for Daffy Duck?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear not.

The name seems to have originated by his antics when audience saw him (before he had an official name) in the short *Porky's Duck Hunt*.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daffy_Duck)

> Daffy first appeared in Porky's Duck Hunt, released on April 17, 1937. The cartoon was directed by Tex Avery and animated by Bob Clampett. Porky's Duck Hunt is a standard hunter/prey pairing for which Leon Schlesinger's studio was famous, but Daffy **(barely more than an unnamed bit player in this short)** was something new to moviegoers: an assertive, completely unrestrained, combative protagonist. Clampett later recalled:
>
> > "At that time, audiences weren't accustomed to seeing a cartoon character do these things. And so, when it hit the theaters it was an explosion. People would leave the theaters talking about this **daffy duck**."

[image]

<sub>Daffy as he first appeared in Porky's Duck Hunt (1937).</sub>